# Canvas not being drawn after move to Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, canvas

I have a project that has been written without a framework and works fine. Photos are displayed on a page. Clicking on one opens a modal and the image is displayed on a canvas in the modal.

This is the javascript used to open the modal **imageModal** and draw the photo onto the canvas called **photoImage**, with **e** being the image that has been clicked on.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("photoImage");
var canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function viewPhoto(e) {
    $("#imageModal").modal("show");

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = e.src;

    canvas.width = image.width; // Width does not get set 
    canvas.height = image.height;  // Height does not get set 
    canvasCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);  // Photo does not get drawn
}
```

I have now used the exact same code in a Laravel project but it does not draw the picture onto the canvas. I have checked the properties of the canvas in both projects and they are the same.

For example the canvas is picking up th height property correctly in both projects but  it does not change the size of the canvas in the Laravel project.

[image]

What could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("photoImage")[0]; //it return an array of object 
var canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
canvasCtx.drawImage(image, 6, 6);  // Photo does not get drawn
```

also you can use typeo `canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 6, 6)`

Comment: This does not do it I am afraid - thanks for trying. I actually got it working by using defining the canvas within the function.